# Free Android app / website to create street based polygons and export them (GeoJSON, gpx)?

Tags: polygon, export, software-recommendations, tools, city

I'm looking for a very simple app / website that allows selecting multiple points on the map to create a polygon that can be exported as a gpx / GeoJSON file.

The idea is to communicate special areas in a neighbourhood where a service can be delivered (on the street)

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. We specialize in questions of the "How to do something *very specific* on my *very complicated* GIS software?" variety. So we're probably not the best community to help you find a simple, user-friendly app (my GIS software has at least a hundred buttons visible on the screen at one time, not to mention all the thousands of tools and processing algorithms I can access from the menus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contradicting  my own comment, here are a few suggestions (not recommendations) I found by some quick searches. I tried the websites but not the apps.

Websites:

- [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/draw/): website that lets you draw points and lines (but not polygons) on a map and export it as a gpx
- http://geojson.io/ : website that lets you draw points, lines and polygons and export as geojson.

Apps:

- [Map Plus](https://duweis.com/en/mapplus.html): This app lets you draw points, lines, circles and polygons and export them as GPX
- [Scribblemaps](https://www.scribblemaps.com/tools/create-gpx-files): draw points, lines and polygons and export to GPX